# Spring Roo - Command 'service' not found

Tags: java, soa, spring-roo

I'm new to Roo (and Java in general). I'm following [Hantsy's tutorial](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-sandbox/wiki/Create-A-Cloud-Ready-Spring-Project-with-Roo) and am running in to problems trying to create the service.

> roo> service --entity ~.model.Conference --interface ~.service.ConferenceService
>
> Command 'service --entity ~.model.Conference --interface ~.service.ConferenceService' not found (for assistance press TAB or type "hint" then hit ENTER)
>
> addon search --requiresCommand "service" found no matches

Any ideas on why?

I'm using Roo 1.2.4 Release (no STS)

Answer (score 4):

While following "Spring in Action" I encountered the same problem with Roo 1.2.4.

Try using `roo> service type` instead of just `roo> service`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The only thing I could find is this:

> If you would like to use a services layer, since release 1.2.0 Roo
>   offers automatic service layer integration for your application.
>   Please refer to the service layer section in the application layering
>   chapter for further details.

I just built my application without running that command. That is the problem with most of the tutorials I am finding, they are out of date.

Comment: I looked up the Applicaiton Layering section at http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/base-layers.html

However, it too goes on to use the service commmand on the CLI.

I can build my project as well. But, I believe it's building without the service layer :(

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with Roo 1.2.4. However it works with Roo 1.2.3. So you can create the service layer in 1.2.3 and the rest in 1.2.4. It worked for me.
According to Roo 1.2.4 documentation, that command should work.